# Disable Angular Slimscroll

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, slimscroll

Angular slimscroll (https://github.com/ziscloud/angular-slimscroll) can be implemented via this:

```
<div slimscroll="{slimscrollOption: value}">
    Scroll Content
</div>
```

But on certain cases I want to disable slimscroll. How can that be done?

Comment: Try using disableFadeOut, by default it is false

Comment: @stanze Isn't that disableFadeOut will always keep the bar there? I want to disable or totally remove it. Is it possible to be done?